# Opening Mode(Initial View) for the PDF File is missing Using Ghostscript

Tags: ghostscript

To Enable the Fastwebview and PDF version to set 1.7 am using Ghostscript.

Input PDF is having the Opening Mode option, After execute the below command Output PDF is not set with the Opening mode.

```
gs -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dFastWebView=true -dCompatibilityLevel=1.7 -sOutputFile=output.pdf input.pdf
```

Kindly let me know how to handle this.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by the 'Opening Mode'.

Comment: Visible view of PDF file, left side Bookmarks/Thumbnails display and Fitwidth mode. In Acrobat Professional use Ctrl+D to view the details in Initial view=>Navigation Tab,Page Layout,Magnification...

Comment: That's not preserved by the Ghostscript PDF interpreter, so if you want that, you'll have to add it yourself, either by modifying the PDF interpreter to generate an appropriate pdfmark, or you'll have to preprocess a PostScript file with an appropriate pdfmark.